# Is there a way to limit selections in the Rails FormBuilder datetime select helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, formbuilder

I want to use [FormBuilder](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder)'s `datetime_select` helper to create dropdowns for a datetime field and want to specify which minute values to use in the drop down (let's say, I want to use 0, 15, 30 and 45.)

Is there some hidden option to `f.datetime_select` that will let me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *`:minute_step`* option like this

```
<%= f.datetime_select :start_datetime, :ampm => true, :minute_step => 15 %>
```

Comment: I was _this_ close to typing in the answer myself :) Just found it in `actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb` in the [rails codebase](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/97f2c4129ae23ee074986a588628acc689a86462/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L753)